# Dynamic block name in TWIG

Tags: twig

I need to add multiple blocks in my template, every with different name.

```
{% for item from items %}
    {% block item.name %}sometext{% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I get error. How can I do this ?

In

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load blocks dynamically using the `block` function.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ block( item.name )|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

[Twig documentation for the `block` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/block.html)

Comment: The `from` is not valid Twig, and if this worked it wouldn't create blocks with dynamic names - it would drop in the content from existing blocks

Comment: You are right. Copied from the original question, but it was supposed to be a `in`. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?! It is not possible in twig to add dynamic names to blocks.

Answer (score 9):

Dynamic block names are not possible with Twig. There has been a discussion about it over at [GitHub](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/298).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you can do this (use parent context):

*parent.html.twig*

```
{% for item from items %} 
  {% set currentLoopItemName = item.name %}
  {% block item_loop %}sometext{% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

*override.html.twig*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block item_loop %} 
  {% if item.name == 'custom' %}
      // do something
  {% else %}
     {{ parent() }}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do the same thing and found a solution using the [template_from_string](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html) function.

*_items.html.twig*

```
{% for item in items %}
 {{ '{% block ' ~ item.name ~ ' %}'}}
 sometext
 {{ '{% endblock %}' }}
{% endfor %}
enter code here
```

*page.html.twig*

```
{% embed template_from_string(include('_items.html.twig')) %}
 {% block someItemName %} someDifferentText {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

What's happening is the block tags are initially being created as text. Then we use the [include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/include.html) function to get the rendered content of `_items`, as a string. Finally, we convert that string to a working template (which we can [embed](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/embed.html) or [extend](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/extends.html)).

This works because the `template_from_string` function will create and compile a template at runtime, where as normally twig is compiled before hand and unchanged at runtime.